# CSS code not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

wondering if anybody can help a newbie? My code seems to work fine in Chrome but it doesn't display in IE.

The intention of the code is to show or hide a piece of text. This works fine in Chrome, but does not load correctly in IE10. Due to restrictions with the application I am using, I am unable to use javascript or any derivative.

Apologies if I have overlooked an article or post on this topic already, but I cannot see a relevant solution.

```css
.answer,
#shown,
#hideaway:target {
  display: none;
}

#hideaway:target+#shown,
#hideaway:target~.answer {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="#hideaway" id="hideaway">Click here for text</a>
<a href="#shown" id="shown">Hide text</a>
<div class="answer">
  <P>Text Goes Here</P>
</div>
```

Thanks in anticipation for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `display: inital`, to `block`. Because initial is not supported by any version of IE

```css
.answer,
#shown,
#hideaway:target {
  display: none;
}

#hideaway:target+#shown,
#hideaway:target~.answer {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#hideaway" id="hideaway">Click here for text</a>
<a href="#shown" id="shown">Hide text</a>
<div class="answer">
  <P>Text Goes Here</P>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the IE developer tools, you probably would have found the answer.

Anyway, [initial is not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

As answer is a div, `display: initial` will be the same as `display: block`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx IE css support :)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you proposed an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The initial keyword is not supported in Internet Explorer 11 and earlier versions.

Use Display:block instead .

```
<style>
.answer,
#shown,
#hideaway:target{
display: none;
}
#hideaway:target + #shown,
#hideaway:target ~ .answer{
display: block;}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<a href="#hideaway" id="hideaway">Click here for text</a>
<a href="#shown" id="shown">Hide text</a>
<div class="answer">
<P>Text Goes Here</P>
</div>
</body>
```